# Ubuntu 12.10 on Intel Atom tablet

Tags: installation, 12.10, windows-8, tablet

I have an Intel Atom n2600 tablet which was running Windows 8, but got excited about Ubuntu and decided to install Ubuntu 12.10 on it.  It detected all necessary hardware (camera, WiFi, bluetooth etc) and touch worked the moment it booted to GUI screen.  I have external cdrom and keyboard only, no mouse since the touch is working perfectly well.  But, after installation, it ejects the CD, and then it stalls. After manual rebooting, it will stop at the black and white screen with the ok things.

Any help to make it work?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your hardware if you need help. Also, I do not think this is the right place to ask, as the question is not specific enough to merit a place in askubuntu.com. In general, Windows 8 tablets have several restrictions, both hardware and software-based, including possibly a non-standard BIOS/UEFI, secure bootloader requirements and could have nonstandard hardware for which Ubuntu does not (yet) have drivers. I'm sure sooner or later there will be ways to run Linux on those machines, but -- again -- any solutions will probably focus on specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ubuntu doesn't support the integrated graphics of Intel Atom N2600.
But you can try these steps:

1. Reboot the tablet.
2. Press 'e' key in grub screen to edit grub.
3. Replace 'quiet splash' with 'i915.modeset=1' or 'i915.modeset=0' or 'xforcevesa'.

Hope this'll help you.